# Brand new boiler only provides a 15 minute hot shower

Tags: boiler

My folks got a brand new boiler last year that is supposed to “continuously” heat water with no hot water tank. Our old system we replaced would run over an hour at least (I never once ran out of hot water) so imagine our surprise after spending thousands to replace the old system to end up taking cold showers after only 15-20 minutes of run time. Is this normal for this type of tankless heater?

Thanks!

**Edit to add some more system information:
It’s a water heater that functions as a zone of the boiler. It’s not considered a “tankless” system I guess. It is called an Intertek indirect hot water heater.

I’m really just wondering if it is normal for this system to only provide at the most 20 minutes of hot shower water before running cold without any other devices (laundry, dishwasher, etc) running at the same time.

Thanks in advance for any information!

Comment: One of the advantages of a tankless water heater is to avoid running out of hot water.  For your testing, were others also using hot water during the time period in question, such as a dishwasher or faucet?  Tankless is limited by the instantaneous usage of hot water, not quantity over time.

Comment: Please revise to provide information about your hardware. Otherwise we're making guesses and your question becomes too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Matthew! The hot water runs out even quicker if we run a dishwasher or laundry (maybe 10 minutes) so when we shower we are sure not to run anything else. So it’s really only giving us 15-20 minutes of hot water in the shower without any other devices drawing from the system. Isherwood, I will post more info about the hardware when I am able to get that information from my father I am not very knowledgeable of this stuff unfortunately!

Comment: Did the new system ever provide more than 15 minutes of shower hot water?

Comment: Hi Armand, no it has never provided more than 15/20 minutes of shower hot water since it was installed last year. It was installed in the summer so we didn’t really notice until the fall when we would want to take a little longer of a shower. I still haven’t been able to speak to my father about the system hardware as he is away on vacation until tomorrow. Hopefully I will have a little more info to share then!

Answer (score 2):

An indirect water heater connected to a boiler uses a circulating boiler loop through a tank or heat exchanger to heat your domestic water.

In your case it's likely an indirect tank, and it runs out of water.

The indirect water tank usually has a thermostat which tells the boiler to begin heating/circulating. Verify that this thermostat is actually connected! One common issue with these systems is that a hotter boiler temperature is needed to heat your domestic water tank. But if your boiler is so hot, you don't actually want domestic water to be that hot.

You need thermostatic mixing setups which allows your tank temperature to be very high (like dangerously hot). These blend in cold water to bring your water supply back down to your target temperature.

For example imagine your tank is at 175F, but you actually want your tap water to be 135F. You configure the mixing valve to add the desired amounts. But consider that if your tank is at 135F then your capacity is basically the same as your tank capacity. But if your tank is at 175 then your hot water capacity might be double! Because you might be using a 50/50 blend of hot and cold.

It's hard to give you a solution without understanding your water system. Boiler loops can be great, but there are more variables than usual and not all plumbers are experienced with them.

Comment: Thanks for all of this information, Matthew!